# save writableimage to file in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How want to save the image of a canvas to a file.

```
var img = new WriteableBitmap(canvas1, null);
Image i = new Image();
i.Source = img;
var bitmap = new Bitmap(i);
```

I tried to use bitmap.Save( for saving the image but Bitmap is not supported by silverlight.
How would you save WriteableBitmap to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WriteableBitmap` has a `Pixels` collection which can be used to access the rendered image.  However you really need to get it stored in a known format (preferable PNG).

The [imagetools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) codeplex project can do that for you.

See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/12/saving-images-bmp-png-etc-in-wpf-silverlight.aspx) for a simple example of using it for your purposes.