# How To upload content of RadRichTextBox

Tags: silverlight

I have Telerik RadRichTextBox. Here is designing

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox Name="radRchTxtBoxEdit" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White"
LayoutMode="Flow" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" TextInput="radRchTxtBoxEdit_TextInput">
```

I want the snapshot of the Rich Text Box's content. Is there any possible way to take the snapshot of the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Using PrintDocument class you can take (snapshot/print) of any UIElement or Control. Declare PrintDocument, assign RadRichTextBox to PageVisual in PrintPage Event.(i.e e.PrintPage  = radRchTxtBoxEdit).

Here is the link to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to save the document as an image and then do something with it. The following should work.

You can generate a bitmap from any UIElement using:

```
WriteableBitmap GetImageForUIElement(UIElement source)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(source, null);
    bmp.Invalidate();

    return bmp;
}
```

Just `feeding your RadRichTextBox` control into this method wont suffice however, as it `will just create an image of the visible area`.

`To generate the whole page`, you must drill into the `Visual Tree` of the RadRichTextBox control to find the [DocumentPagePresenter](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/t_telerik_windows_documents_ui_documentpagepresenter.html)

This will help with finding the correct child control:

```
T GetDescendent<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int children = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < children; i++)
    {
        var element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
        if (element is T)
        {
            return (T)element;

        }
        else
        {
            element = GetDescendent<T>(element);
            if (element != null)
            {
                return (T)element;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The WritableBitmap can be used directly as the Source for an Image control, 
but there is no native way to convert this object into a file system object, however there are a few options.

1. You could send the raw pixel data to a web service and do your saving there. (WriteableBitmap.Pixels)
2. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949545/save-writableimage-to-file-in-silverlight) for ways to save to other image formats

...

And for the sake of a complete answer: 
Here's some XAML to look over [(Straight from Telerik)](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radrichtextbox-features-working-with-radrichtextbox.html)

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox" >
    <telerik:RadDocument LayoutMode="Paged">
        <telerik:Section PageMargin="10, 10, 10, 10">
            <telerik:Paragraph>
                <telerik:ImageInline Width="236" Height="50" UriSource="/Silverlight.Help.RadRichTextBoxSamples;component/Demos/Images/RadRichTextBox.png" />
            </telerik:Paragraph>
            <telerik:Paragraph TextAlignment="Center">
                <telerik:Span Text="Thank you for choosing Telerik" />
                <telerik:Span FontWeight="Bold" Text=" RadRichTextBox!" />
            </telerik:Paragraph>
            <telerik:Paragraph>
                <telerik:Span FontWeight="Bold" Text="RadRichTextBox" />
                <telerik:Span Text=" is a control that is able to display and edit rich-text content including formatted text arranged in pages, paragraphs, spans (runs) etc." />
            </telerik:Paragraph>
            <telerik:Table LayoutMode="AutoFit">
                <telerik:TableRow>
                    <telerik:TableCell>
                        <telerik:Paragraph>
                            <telerik:Span Text="Cell 1" />
                        </telerik:Paragraph>
                    </telerik:TableCell>
                    <telerik:TableCell>
                        <telerik:Paragraph>
                            <telerik:Span Text="Cell 2" />
                        </telerik:Paragraph>
                    </telerik:TableCell>
                </telerik:TableRow>
                <telerik:TableRow>
                    <telerik:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                        <telerik:Paragraph>
                            <telerik:Span Text="Cell 3" />
                        </telerik:Paragraph>
                    </telerik:TableCell>
                </telerik:TableRow>
            </telerik:Table>
        </telerik:Section>
    </telerik:RadDocument>

</telerik:RadRichTextBox>
<Image x:Name="MyRichTextImage" />
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
```

And here's the button click handler

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DocumentPagePresenter doc = GetDescendent<DocumentPagePresenter>(MyRichTextBox);

    if (doc != null)
    {
        MyRichTextImage.Source = GetImageForUIElement(doc);
    }
}
```